# Get field type in templates

Tags: templating, craft3, field

I need to get the field type in my templates like I used to do: `field.getField.type` but that does not seem to be working in Craft 3 anymore. The result is always `null`. It also seems that the »type« column is gone completely from the craft_fields table.

How do I get the field type in Craft 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be other ways, but here's one possibility:

```
{{ craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('yourFieldHandle').className() }}
```

This will return a string of `craft\fields\PlainText`, `craft\fields\Lightswitch` etc, which you can then use in conditionals/switch statements.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! But why is it suddenly that complicated?

Comment: A question I ask myself almost daily... not so much in relation to Craft, but the whole web dev industry. I'm not best placed to answer it in relation to Craft, but I would hazard a guess that these kind of changes relate to the fact that Craft 3 is far more sophisticated than Craft 2: the added sophistication means technical debt needs to be very tightly managed, and limiting a field's output to be a simple string instead of a complex object with actionable methods like `getField()` is probably a significant performance boost. Just guessing, who knows...